# Registers error on iPad OS 15+

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, push

I'm facing a problem while using React Native. Can someone help me? Thx~.

**Env**

MarketingCloud React Native SDK version: 7.4.3

Device: IPad OS 15.2/15.0

**Desc**

When the user registers on IPadOS 15+ device, only basic data can be uploaded, but mobile push data cannot.

I call `MCReactModule.logSdkState` after `MCReactModule.setContactKey`, and get the result.

```
...
"Last Successfully Sent Registration" : {
        "sdk_Version" : "7.4.0",
        "dST" : false,
        "subscriberKey" : "subscriberKey...",
        "location_Enabled" : false,
        "etAppId" : "app id",
        "platform_Version" : "15.2",
        "quietPushEnabled" : false,
        "tags" : [
          "ALL",
          "IOS",
          "iPad"
        ],
...
```

I can only see some system field such as `ContactKey`, `ContactId` on the console.
[image]
The Data in the part of MobilePush Demographics is empty.
[image: MobilePush Demographics]
By the way, I'm sure it works fine on the other devices(iPad < 15 or any iPhone device).

Answer (score 1):

Please update to v7.6+ as this has been addressed.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
But I found the latest release of Marketing Cloud React Native SDK is 7.4.3.234.0.
Do you mean I need to upgrade separately the SDK versions for Android and IOS dependencies included in React Native?

Comment: I will take this to the team.  An updated iOS SDK has been released that addresses your issue.  It _should_ be baked into the React plugin.  Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for you help, I will try this suggestion.

Comment: Hello, I try to upgrade the IOS SDK version to 7.6.0(`- MarketingCloudSDK (7.6.0)`), but I am still facing the same problem. Do I need to try some other changes?

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a known issue regarding registration with iPad OS 15+. You can check it [here](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001U9GbQAK).